# IE11 - failed to open http://localhost:8080

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer, vuejs2, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to access my VueJS application running on my node server on IE11 by accessing the URL `http://localhost:8080`. However I cant access the same as only a blank screen appears. I have babel polyfill installed and imported in my main file and have babel presets already setup in babelrc file.

My app is currently running and is accessible on Chrome but not on IE11.

I don't get a single error message in console and have no clue what could be going wrong. Has anyone ever faced this?

Comment: Which version of VueJS version are you using? Please try to use F12 developer tools to check whether there have some error? can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I have create a new vue sample with refer to [this article](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#using-the-gui), it works well in IE browser. Besides, here is an article about [VusJS Browser Compatibility](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#browserslist), you could check it.

Comment: try to add an `s` as in `https...`

Comment: You need to use polyfills. https://jacklyons.me/how-to-fix-vuejs-not-working-in-ie11/ or  here: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use polyfills. IE11 does not support ES2015, it needs to be transiled by babel. There seem to be various ways of doing this.

Please check this guide: [jacklyons.me/how-to-fix-vuejs-not-working-in-ie11](https://jacklyons.me/how-to-fix-vuejs-not-working-in-ie11/)

or here: [cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html)